# Understanding this DNN model and why it does not work on multi-label classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am fairly new to Keras and DNN in general and starting from some tutorials, I have managed to create a model for classifying sentences. The model is shown below. To be honest, I do not know for sure what is the intuition behind it and why it works. So this is my question.

```
def create_model():
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=300,
                                input_length=100)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(embedding_layer)
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
    model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
    #model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    ###### multiclassification #########
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')) #I want to replace the above line with this for multi-classification but this didnt work
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And here is my understanding: The model starts with training word embeddings on the corpus (of sentences), and represent each sentence as a vector of word vectors (embedding_layer). The dropout layer then forces the model to not rely on specific words. Convolution has a similar effect of identifying phrases/n-grams as opposed to just individual words; then an LSTM follows to learn sequences of phrases/n-grams that may be useful features; The `Globalmaxpooling1D` layer then 'flattens' the LSTM output as features for the final classification (dense layer).

Does this make any sense? I also do not quite understand the interaction between the `maxpooling1D` layer and the `lstm` layer. What's the `input_shape` to `lstm` and what does the output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your intuition is right. Everything you told holds. About `MaxPooling1D` - it's a way to downsample the output from `Conv1D`. The output from this layer will be 4-times smaller than the original output from `Conv1D` (so input to `LSTM` will have a length of 25 with the same number of features. Just to show you how it works:

output from `Conv1D` :

`0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, -1`

input to `LSTM` :

`1 (max from 0, 1, 1, 0), 5  (max from -1, 2, 3, 5), 2 (max from 1, 2, 1, -1)`

**Edit**
I haven't noticed `categorical_crossentropy` and activations. So:

1. If your output is one out of 3 classes you could use `categorical_crossentropy` and `sigmoid` but then your input cannot be interpretable as probability distribution but as class score (prediction  is equal to a class with a highest score). Better option is to use `softmax` which produces a probability distribution over classes.
2. In case of 3 classes prediction (not mutually exclusive) due to Keras implementation you should use `binary_crossentropy` even though it's mathematically equivalent to `categorical_crossentropy`. It's because `keras` normalizes outputs from the last layer and makes them to sum up to 1. This might seriously harm your training.

Comment: Thanks to both that are relevant to my question but since this directly answers it... I am still trying to work out the data shapes between layers. Why lstm have 25 length of the same features? I thought the layers are reducing features, not length? So embedding layer outputs 100 (words, or length) x 300 (features), conv1d produces 100 (filters, or channels) feature maps, each of a size 100 (words) x 75 (300/4); then shouldnt max pooling further reduce this to 75/4?  Also in this case for input to lstm, what is the batch size? is step=100?  Thanks

Comment: This would work like this if `stride` would be set to 4. Filter size equal to 4 means that each output from `Conv1D` collected information from 4 timesteps.

Comment: sorry, do you mean 'kernel_size' in conv1d?

Answer (score 0):

**Multiclass models:**

The multiclassification model ending with `Dense(3,activation='sigmoid')` is ok for a multiclass with 3 possible classes.

But it should only use `'categorical_crossentropy'` if there is only one correct class among the 3. In this case, the activation function should be `'softmax'`.

A 'softmax' will guarantee that all the classes sum 1. It's good when you want only one correct class.
A 'sigmoid' will not care about the relation between the 3 classes, they can coexist as all ones or all zeros. In this case, use a `'binary_crossentropy'`.

**LSTM and GlobalMaxPooling:**

The LSTM input is `(batchSize, timeSteps, featuresOrDimension)`.
The output can be two:

- With `return_sequences = True`: `(batchSize, timeSteps, units)`
- With `return_sequences = False`: `(batchSize, units)`.

Since you chose the True case, there is the timeSteps dimension, and the `GlobalMaxPooling1D` will take the highest value in that dimension and discard the others, resulting in `(batchSize,units)`.

It's pretty much like using only `LSTM(units,return_sequences=False)`. But this one takes the last step in the sequence, while the maxpooling will take the maximum step.

Comment: What does it mean that `keras` will complain?

Comment: I could have sworn it would give me error messages.... I'm sure I've read those.... but maybe it's in a different situation. What I remember is that there were some cases where I couldn't use categorical crossentropy. I got to learn what these losses and activations were because of those messages....